# Laravel 7 - Send ajax request to fetch latest (n) of messages for a specific contact in inbox and render them into page fetched _messages

Tags: laravel

[JSON-data needed to be rendered on fetched_messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c90Nh.png)

ChatController @method "fetchMessages"

```
/**
 * Fetch all messages related to specific contact
 *
 * @return Message
 */
public function fetchMessages($id)
{

    $messages = DB::table('messages')
       ->where(function ($query) use($id) {
           $query->where('sender_id', Auth::user()->id)
                 ->where('receiver_id', $id);
       })
       ->orWhere(function ($query) use($id) {
           $query->where('sender_id', $id)
                 ->where('receiver_id', Auth::user()->id);
       })
       ->latest()
       ->paginate(20);
    return Response::json($messages);
  
}
```

Ajax for getting the id from blade to ChatController

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('.tab-next').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let index = $(this);
        let userId = $(this).attr('user-id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/messages/fetch/' + userId,
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
   
            }
        });
    });
    
});
```

Chat Routes on web.php

```
Route::get('messages', 'ChatsController@index')->name('msg');
Route::get('messages/fetch/{id}', 'ChatsController@fetchMessages')->name('msg.fetch');
Route::get('messages/post', 'ChatsController@sendMessage')->name('msg.post');
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: why you should dont use ? ,orderByDesc('id')->limit(n)->paginate(20)

Comment: I Don't get your question sorry, can u illustrate more ?